# Change ng-show in another controller?

Tags: angularjs

I want to change ng-show in another controller than ng-show is.

```js
myApp.controller('popupCtrl', function() {});

myApp.controller('changePopup', function($rootScope){
  // now i wanna show my Ppopup
  $rootScope.popup = true;
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="popupCtrl">
  <div ng-show="popup">
    Popuptext
  </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work... How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to create factory that will hold this `popup` value in, and use this factory in both controllers!

Comment: Not necessarily ! the rootScope is available across application and the code should work unless the the piece of code is in an isolated scope.

Comment: @Abhi - Very true. I can see people posting alternatives as answers without assisting the user to solve his problem. I don't know how many of them have tried to run the code and realize that it runs.

Comment: @CharlieH alternative answer assist the user to solve his problem, it depends at what level his problem is being solved at. I've taken a high level approach so rather than just "fixing" his code, i've given him the ability to make a judgement call about how to proceed his current solution.

Comment: After you told me my code should work I searched for my mistake. I wrote
<div ng-show="popup=true"> instead of <div ng-show="popup===true"> -.-

Thanks for your help! I will now improve my solution.

Comment: popup=true is an assignment and not comparison. Try to print {{popup}} and see what you get.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't saw my fault.

Comment: @Callum Linington - You can see from the comments of the user that your alternative method has not helped him.

Comment: Piuma, this does work for you in this scenario but if you want for example to execute a function when $rootScope.popup is changed you will need to either use a factory/service or $broadcast/$emit with $on as the answers below show.

Answer (score 3):

So first thing, you should never add to the `$rootScope` or change it in anyway. It has been optimised by the angular team.

Second thing, there is no need to involve the `$rootScope`.

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZl8S2WNpj2kDWiZvmfs?p=preview) showing how to communicate across two controllers.

The key is the event aggregator pattern:

```
Communicator.register(function (newValue) {
    vm.value = Communicator.value;
});
```

I created a function in the `Communicator` to register a callback function. The aim is that when a value gets changed the callback function is fired off. I.e. an event is triggered (change event).

The second key part is fire that change event off:

```
Communicator.change(!Communicator.value);
```

Here we pass through to the `change` function a new value which will do two things:

1. Update the internal value so we can keep track of it
2. Loop through all the registered callbacks and execute them passing in the new value.

By implementing this pattern, we can minimise the extent to which we communicate around our application (`$rootScope` can have a tendency to traverse the scope heirarchy when you `$broadcast`).

Now we can follow more closely the principle of single responsibility. Our class is aptly named in its current scope, when we look at this factory we can tell it is supposed to "communicate".

Finally, with a global event aggregator pattern (`$rootScope`) it is far more difficult to keep track of where these events are being broadcast from, and where they'll end up. Here we don't have that issue

Comment: Did you run the snippet from the question and realize that it works?

Comment: @CharlieH Doesn't matter if it works or not, I'm giving an alternative solution.... Since he has asked, I'm suggesting a different approach

Comment: He shows a working snippet and say it doesn't work. Showing another way to do it doesn't solve his problem since the issue is not in the snippet.

Comment: @CharlieH I haven't shown an answer to his snippet, I've showed a solution to his problem that he has presented. My solution will solve his problem not fix his code

Comment: How do you know the real reason for the correct snippet to not work properly in his code? You are only providing a way to share variables between controllers. That mechanism is already correct in his code through $rootScope. You are just giving an alternative to a functional part of his problem. Your method may or may not work. You don't have enough data to tell exactly.

Comment: I have stated so many times that I'm not attempting to fix his code. He has very clearly and concisely communicated the high level problem that he is trying to solve. By the standards set by SO he has given a code snippet of what he has tried so far. I have actively ignored the code snippet in order to give him another solution entirely (one I believe is more robust). This ISN'T a direct answer but and alternative high level solution @CharlieH

Comment: I upvoted your answer, Charlie H is clearly having a bad day :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use $rootScope.$broadcast

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/EmJnZvXFRWv6vjKF7QCd

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('popupCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope,$scope) {

 $scope.popup = false;

 $rootScope.$on('changePopup', function(event, data) {
  $scope.popup = !$scope.popup;
});


}]);

myApp.controller('changePopup', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {

$scope.changePopup = function() {
$rootScope.$broadcast('changePopup', 'data could be sent here');
}
}]);
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="popupCtrl">
<div ng-show="popup">
  Popuptext
</div>
```

```
<div ng-controller="changePopup">
<button ng-click="changePopup()">Change the popup</button>
</div>
```

Using a service/factory is a better solution for cross controller communication if you are working on a large application, but for a smaller app I would say using $broadcast, $emit and $on is sufficient.

Comment: Did you run the snippet from the question and realize that it works?

Comment: I have been new to angular once and wondered about the same thing so I've assumed to know what Piuma is asking for, we will see once he has read the answers. It's one thing to set a variable on rootscope and access it in another controller, it's another thing to communicate and listen to changes cross controller.

Comment: He shows a working snippet and say it doesn't work. Showing another way to do it doesn't solve his problem since the issue is not in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo for you - sorry I changed the controller names,  but I am sure you will be able to build on this.  Good luck

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('c1', function($scope) {
    // now i wanna show my Ppopup
    $scope.popup = false;
    $scope.$on('popup', function() {
      $scope.popup = true;
    });

  })
  .controller('changepopup', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    // now i wanna show my Ppopup
    $scope.clicker = function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('popup')
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="c1">
    <div ng-show="popup">
      Popuptext
    </div>
  </div>

  <button ng-controller="changepopup" ng-click="clicker()">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you run the snippet from the question and realize that it works?

Comment: @CharlieH since Piuma asked for a solution with another controller the answer from Simon seems to be valid, no matter if the original works (but not as intended)

Comment: The question shows a working snippet and says it doesn't work in his code. The answer should address this issue without showing another way to do it. The problem is not in the snippet since it is valid. So this answer doesn't provide a solution to the original problem.

Comment: The question was 'how can I change the value of `$scope.popup` from `popupCtrl`, which I answered

Comment: The user thought that the problem was what you answered for. But his problem was not that and you, as an expert, while seeing his snippet works, should have brought him to the correct course by a better answer.